# Tkinter: Checkbox variable is always zero

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I want to create a checkbox that would invoke an enable function. This works as follows:

```
self.lol = tk.IntVar(False)
self.c = tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Advanced settings", variable=self.lol, command=self.enable())
self.c.grid(column=3,row=5,sticky="EW")

def enable(self):
    print (self.lol.get())
    if self.lol.get()==1:
        self.advanced()
    if self.lol.get()==0:
        try:
            self.gpuvar.grid_forget()
            print ("lalka")
        except:
            pass
```

So, the enable function is working and as I run the program, it outputs zero. But when I check the checkbox, no output is generated at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.c = tk.Checkbutton(..., command=self.enable())
                                                ^^
```

In above line, you are calling the `enable()` method as soon as you create the widget. Pass method itself as command not its return value by removing paranthesis.

```
self.c = tk.Checkbutton(..., command=self.enable)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped!